# Dart: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-sharedpreference

There are 2 functions. One must return String other save this String in with SharedPreferences.
The problem is, that by using `prefs.getString()` I get not a String but another object.
The error called: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.

```
  getCurrentCityFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('currentCity');
  }

  Future<void> setCurrentCityInSharedPreferences(String newCity) async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('currentCity', newCity);
  }
```

I have tried to rewrite function to

```
Future<String?> getCurrentCityFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('currentCity');
  }
```

but then I get as string Deskription of object: Instance of 'Future<String?>'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508574/a-value-of-type-string-cant-be-assigned-to-a-variable-of-type-string)

Answer (score 2):

your set string type is simply string and get type is String?
so change set type like this

```
 Future<void> setCurrentCityInSharedPreferences(String? newCity) async{
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('currentCity', newCity!);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to get `currentCity` from SharedPreferences you get an object of type `String?`. This basically means that the returned object is a string that can also be null (in case there is no data stored with the key `currentCity` in SharedPreferences).

So, you can't do something like:

```
String s = prefs.getString('currentCity');
```

You have to handle the possibility of the value being null.

You can either declare the variable as `String?` like this:

```
String? s = prefs.getString('currentCity');
```

Or you can do something like:

```
String s = prefs.getString('currentCity') ?? "No City";
```

So, if you want to handle null values in the `getCurrentCityFromSharedPreferences` function then what you can do is:

```
Future<String> getCurrentCityFromSharedPreferences() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('currentCity') ?? "No City";
}
```

You can replace "No City" with any value that you want to show when there is no city saved in SharedPreferences.